# How to call url which depends on input in Thymeleaf?

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a form in Thymeleaf in which there is a drop down list and a button. I want to call an URL when the button is clicked which depends on the value of drop down selected. From the dropdown, `serviceId` is selected and then the URL also uses `serviceId`. How do I do this?

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/heart2heart/format/{serviceId}}" method="get" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
    <select th:field="*{serviceId}" class="form-control">
        <option th:each="service : ${services}"
                  th:value="${service.id}"
                  th:text="${service.description}">Customer Service</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" name="addRow" th:text="#{button.download}"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Download</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combination of javascript/jquery and integrating it into your form.

So first you need to set some id's:

```
 <select id="someidyougaveit" th:field="*{serviceId}" class="form-control">
//code
        </select>

    <form id="yourform" action="#" th:action="@{/heart2heart/format/{serviceId}}" method="get" role="form">
    // code
    </form>
```

Then using Javascript change the action after obtaining the value:

```
var frm = document.getElementById('yourform');
if(frm) {
   frm.action = 'yoururl'+$("#someidyougaveit").val(); 
}
```